# Lspci and Lshw won't run

Tags: 17.10, lspci

Fresh install of 17.10. Zenbook Pro UX501. Neither lspci nor lshw will run (w/ or w/out sudo and regardless of flags attached). No error is output from either. The terminal just sits blankly indefinitely without any response or update.

Comment: Try running `journalctf -f` in one tab, and then `lscpi` in another, and wait for, say, 3 minutes. Check if any output appeared in journalctf output.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Actually, the command to use is `journalctl`, not `journalctf`.

Comment: It started working again. Really not sure why. I am also experiencing this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1720930). Perhaps they are related.